# Azure Synapse: How to use Spark job reference files?

Tags: azure-synapse

I created a Spark job definition following the PySpark section of this tutorial.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-job-definitions#create-an-apache-spark-job-definition-for-pyspark-python

I want to update additional python files in the reference files section of the job definition and use those files in the main python job file.
I tried a few different approaches and get errors that the classed I try to reference can't be found.

How can I use the reference python files in the main job definition?

Comment: When you say "I tried a few different approaches and get errors that the classed I try to reference can't be found.", could you please share the different approaches which you have tried along with the error messages which you are experiencing?

Comment: See my answer on this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70329762/1764764